# Trying to make a fencing map using terrain representation

Tags: java, eclipse, terrain

Right now im looking to make a fence with 1's and 0's to represent terrain. 1 will be the fences, and 0 will be the empty spaces. Here is my code

```
package assignment_2;

public class Fencing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean b = true;
    int i;
    int j;
    int[] [] map = 

        {
                {0, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 4, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 0}
        };
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0){
                b = false;

                if (b = false){
                System.out.println("Map of the land owned:");
                System.out.println(map[i][j]);
                System.out.println("Map does not have the correct format");
                System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);

                }
                else{
                System.out.println("Map of the land owned: ");
                System.out.println(map[i][j]);
                System.out.println("The map is valid");
                return;
                }   
            }
        }       
    }
}
}
```

What i'm trying to make the code do is to display if a map is valid or not. The map cannot be valid if it is made of anything other than 0's or 1's, but for some reason this code is making the map valid no matter what is in it, and is displaying the first error in the map instead of printing out the whole map. I'm trying to make the final result look like this:

```
Map of land owned

0110
1211
1141
1100

The map is not valid
A value of 2 was found at 1,1
A value of 4 was found at 2,2
```

Heres what the result looks like right now

```
Map of the land owned: 
2
The map is valid
```

It seems to be ignoring the b boolean for some reason, does anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: The b problem has been fixed, this is what im getting now

```
Map of the land owned:
2
Map does not have the correct format
--> A value of 2 was found at 1,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's ignoring the `if (b = false)` is because you are using an assignment operator, not a conditional operator. This will always evaluate to true, because you are assigning the value, thus making it true.

Change it to `if (b == false)` or as Balint pointed out `(!b)`.

If you want to print out the whole map, you could do something like this:

```
int indexI = 0;
int indexJ = 0;     

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            System.out.println("Map of the land owned:");
            System.out.println(map[i][j]);
            if (map[i][j] != 1 || map[i][j] != 0){
                b = false;
                indexI = i;
                indexJ = j; 
            }

        }
 }       

if (b == false){
System.out.println("Map does not have the correct format");
System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[indexI][indexJ] + " was found at " + indexI + "," + indexJ);

}
else{
System.out.println("Map of the land owned: ");
System.out.println("The map is valid");
return;
}
```

Comment: Or you know, just use `!b`

Comment: @Bálint you could do that too, depending on your style :)

Comment: I don't know about you, but this is my order: shorter readable > longer readable > shorter unreadable > longer unreadable

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, its displaying the errors properly now, but do you know how to get it to display the entire map instead of the first error?

Comment: If you wanted to display the whole map, you would just keep a reference to whether or not the map was valid, print the whole map, then use your conditional statement to determine whether the map was valid. You just have to change the order of how you do things. Everything is there for you to do it.

Comment: @MemeBoi, also feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem :) Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks, i did. But for some reason when i have "System.out.println(map[i][j]);" it is just printing the first error instead of printing the entire map. If there are no errors it just prints the first number which is the 0,0 coordinate. Do you know how to get the code to print the whole thing? Ive edited the OP to show what im getting

Comment: @MemeBoi I updated my answer. I didn't run it, but you would do something to that effect, where you print out the whole map, then determine if it is valid. I hope that helps.